# Android Studio: Buttons in Grid Layout change size in emulator

Tags: android, grid, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eDOD.png)

I don't know how to make all button sizes the same... I tried making grid to wrap content, it worked, but button sizes were a bit different depending on the number of characters. Does anyone know how to format this stuff?

I tried adding number of rows and columns, gravity, etc, but it didn't change a thing.

Here is my XML code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <Button
        android:text="Do you speak &#10; English?"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/english"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <Button
        android:text="Good Evening"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/goodEvening"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <Button
        android:text="Please"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/please"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <Button
        android:text="My name is"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <Button
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <Button
        android:text="How are you?"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/howAreYou"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <Button
        android:text="I live in"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iLiveIn"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: use linear layout it makes equal layout for all mobiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity) . `android:layout_gravity="fill"` will

> Grow the horizontal and vertical size of the object if needed so it
>   completely fills its container

and here your container size is `match_parent`.So it is filling your layout . Now make your container(GridLayout) `wrap_content` , otherwise use `gravity` attribute properly

Comment: So what gravity would you recommend? I tried changing them, both in grid and buttons...

Comment: @CrashendoDt  i recommend you to use Linear layout for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Change from match_parent to wrap_content if you plan on using GridLayout:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</GridLayout>
```

If not, then use constrain guidelines or linearlayout